# Best way to compare 2 mongoDb collections by field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I try to figure out best approach to match MongoDb collections to find non-existing documents in both.

Imagine, we have original MongoDb collection with application data.

db.Coll1

`{'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'1'}
 {'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'2'}
 {'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'3'}`

where 'externalKey' always contains value and is unique.

Now it is being replaced with another collection with documents of same formats, but with newer data.

Coll2

`{'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'1'}
 {'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'2'}
 {'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'4'}`

Let's say before overwriting Coll2 => Coll1 for business porposes we want to find (and processes):

- documents which are being removed ( in Coll1 it is document  `{'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'3'}`
- documents which are about to be added ( in Coll2 it's  `{'_id': 'someValue', ... 'externalKey':'4'}`

I.e. we are matching Col1 => Coll2 (removals) and Col2 => Col1 (additions).

Comparing to sql concept, it is more like full outer join where both keys are null.

```
SELECT * FROM COLL1 C1

FULL OUTER JOIN COLL2 C2 
WHERE C1.ExternalKey IS NULL 
   AND C2.ExternalKey IS NULL
```

What is the fastest way to perform this operations? 
I mean $lookup, custom code(say, console app thru mongoDb driver) or map reduce?

Let's say updated records are out of scope and don't need to be reprocessed.
MongoDb version does not matter. 
Preferably 3.6. 
Possibly 4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way would be order the data by certain criteria, preferably the ID, and then compare elements from each collection. For example,

```
Collection 1 IDs are:
    1, 2, 3, 5 , 6, 7, 10
Collection 2 IDs are:
    1, 2 3, 4,  5, 6, 8, 9, 10
```

Now you keep 2 indexes i =0 and j =0, one for each collection

```
If collection1[i] == collection2[j] then i++ and j++
```

From the example above, when i =3 and j =3 the values are not equal we do

```
if(collection1[i] > collection2[j]) then add collection2[j] to the adding collection and increase j
```

In the example 4 is added to the adding list

```
if(collection1[i] < collection2[j]) then add collection1[i] to the removal list and increase i
```

When i =5 and j = 6, 7 is missing from the collection 2 so it should be removed

```
Then repeat the above steps
```

If you have huge data base like terabytes you need to use a cursor and read each page from each collection  and then do comparisons above. You can write mongoshell scripts to do it

Comment: That actually might work, thank you. Pagination works either. Will try and respond

Comment: The issue with Pagination is that when you have huge data  like several hundred millions Gbs or terabytes of data, the performance of skip() operation is really bad.  Sometimes it took us 30 minutes to just do one skip()